# What can I infer from this? "process has died [pid 11298, exit code -11]"

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS Hydro.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/163436/what-can-i-infer-from-this?-%22process-has-died-%5Bpid-11298,-exit-code--11%5D%22/) by [expelliarmus](https://answers.ros.org/users/5244/expelliarmus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2014-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Signal 11 usually means a segmentation fault.

If you're running this node as part of a launch file, you can try running it by itself, and try running it in gdb or valgrind.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3